# Javascript - Use 'if-else' or 'if' only for single value assignment?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am curious, for the codes below:

Code 1:

```
var myValue = 10;
if(isBlocked)
  myValue = 20;
```

Code 2:

```
var myValue;
if(isBlocked)
  myValue = 20;
else
  myValue = 10;
```

Both should do the same thing. But I prefer Code 1, as it obviously requires less lines. Is it better to use Code 1 for single value assignment?

**EDIT**

Thank you guys for reminding me about the 'ternary operator'. Before closing the post, i would like to ask: Is 'Evaluate an assignment' similar to 'Evaluate an else statement'? (performance)

Comment: You could alternatively do like this, `var myValue = isBlocked ? 20 : 10;`

Comment: The ternary operator (`?:`) is an expression and can be used within variable declarations.

Comment: How to close this question? failed to find......

Comment: Thank you both for mentioning the 'ternary operator'. I edit the post asking another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes code 1 is better ,few lines are doing the same thing .

You can make it short through ternary operator

```
var myValue = isBlocked ? 20: 10;
```

Comment: Code 1 doesn't do exactly the same thing, as it does evaluate `10` even when it does not need to

Comment: @Bergi so, 'evaluate = 10' VS 'evaluate else' (hope i am asking correctly), is that the same?

Answer (score 2):

The format:

```
var myValue = 10;

if (isBlocked) {
    myValue = 20;
    }
```

is a safe, commonly-deployed approach.

**Reason:**

By initialising `myValue` with a default value of `10`, in all instances where the `if statement` does not run (for whatever reason), `myValue` will definitely continue to have a value of `10`.

Comment: But Code 2 is just as safe - if the if condition is false for whatever reason then the else block runs?

Comment: Yes, assuming there is no syntax error hiding the `if... else` block or the `if... else` block is incorrectly nested etc. If this happens in Code 1, `myValue` still has a default value of `10`. If this happens in Code 2, `myValue` is initialised - but it has no value at all.

Comment: Well one could imagine syntax errors that make code 1 just as invalid :-) And I guess I'd rather get an exception from the value being `undefined` than to have a hidden bug because it's always `10`.

Comment: Yes, the "hidden bug" issue is absolutely a fair point. Perhaps it's safest to say: "case by case, depends on the context."

Comment: I give this a vote, as i think the pre-defined value should be fine. And i think 'evaluate else' is similar to 'evaluate a variable assignment' (correct me if this is wrong). I prefer less line of code. But i think ternary operator is the best answer, as it is the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer code 1 as it is safe that it will always have a value other than `undefined` in `myValue`

If you look at code 2 and by any chance if the `if` condition doesnt gets executed then your `myValue` variable will be `undefined`.
So better use code 1 and chose condition wisely.

***UPDATE
If the `if` condition doesnt gets executed, value of `myValue` wont be `undefined` but you will realize that you dont need that else condition as you want some value assigned to `myValue` if condition is false, so just override when condition is true.

Comment: If the if condition doesn't get executed then the else block will still get executed?

Comment: Yes it will. But then if you look at the code 2, after a while you will realize that you dont need the `else` condition at all because in a case when the `if` condition is not `true` you want to assign it a default value, so better assign a default value before and override if the condition falls `true`

Comment: We don't know wether any of the two values might be considered a "default" value. If it is, I can agree, but in general I would suggest the ternary.

Comment: Well, it depends. If you want the value to be always 10 if condition is not true, then code 1 is best for you. Also, If you are thinking of adding more conditions in future then code 2 should be your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine! It all depends on whether if you will need to add additional comparison in the future. If yes use Code 2, if not use Code 1.